# On Mobile touch devices html text overflow in input refuses to scroll

Tags: javascript, html, css, mobile, touch

I have a basic html text input field in my app like so

```
<input class="note-title" type='text' placeholder='Untitled Note'/>
```

Here is the css on the input

```
note-title
  background-color transparent
  outline 0
  border 0
  width 95%
  color noteTitle
  font-size 20px
  font-weight 400
  opacity 1
  -webkit-appearance none
  overflow scroll
```

For some reason though if the text inside the input is longer than the input itself, I cannot scroll in the x direction no matter what. Even if I focus the input, and use the magnifying tool to try and scroll input to the end it does not work.

On desktop the input scroll in the x direction just fine. Only on mobile I cannot scroll the input in the x direction.

I have tried adding `-webkit-user-select auto` and other css fixes but nothing seems to work.

All I want to do is be able to scroll the input left and right on Mobile devices. Another weird thing is after the input is blurred, the input automatically scroll all the way to the left. Appreciate any help, thanks!

UPDATE:

If I use the hack below, the input can scroll now... but I am wondering why the default does not scroll.

```
# hack to fix the issue where you cannot scroll any inputs from left to right
if Mobile
  startingNoteTitleXPos = 0
  currentNoteTitleXPos = 0

  $('body').on 'touchstart', 'input', (e) ->
    startingNoteTitleXPos = e.offsetX
    currentNoteTitleXPos = e.target.scrollLeft

  $('body').on 'touchmove', 'input', (e) ->
    endingNoteTitleXPos = e.offsetX
    newScrollPos = startingNoteTitleXPos - endingNoteTitleXPos
    e.target.scrollLeft = currentNoteTitleXPos + newScrollPos
```

Comment: hmmm your code works fine here: fiddle.jshell.net/768b4jnp (using dev tools mobile device). except that color noteTiltle doesn't exist

Comment: Thanks Olivier but it also works for me using mobile dev tools... but when you actually try on a mobile device it does not work....